# Why is sshd looking at a non-existent public key file?

Tags: ssh, sshd

In an effort to get SSH keys working I'm tailing the sshd authorization log and I see these lines:

```
debug1: test whether pkalg/pkblob are acceptable
debug1: temporarily_use_uid: 10144/10029 (e=0/0)
debug1: trying public key file /home/cklein/.ssh/authorized_keys
debug1: restore_uid: 0/0
debug1: temporarily_use_uid: 10144/10029 (e=0/0)
debug1: trying public key file /home/cklein/.ssh/authorized_keys2
debug1: restore_uid: 0/0
Failed publickey for cklein from 192.168.8.165 port 46583 ssh2
```

But if I check the `/home/cklein/.ssh/` directory it looks like this:

```
$ ls -al /home/cklein/.ssh/
total 16
drwx------. 2 cklein infoarch 4096 May  3 16:39 .
drwxr-x--x. 9 cklein infoarch 4096 May  3 16:39 ..
-rw-------. 1 cklein infoarch  605 May  3 16:39 authorized_keys
-rw-r--r--. 1 cklein infoarch  226 Apr  4 16:11 known_hosts
```

I used to have an `authorized_keys2` file in that directory, but removed it and have since restarted `sshd`. Why is it still expecting that file to exist?

Also, do you have any guesses as to why the public key is getting rejected?

Comment: Is there a public/private key pair in that directory? I didn't see it in the above output from the .ssh directory.

Comment: What distro is this too, BTW? Is this an older system or a recent one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, the OpenSSH server will look for authorized keys in `.ssh/authorized_keys` and `.ssh/authorized_keys2` unless you set a different value for `AuthorizedKeysFile` in the configuration file at `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`.

For the rest, I can't see any key file in the directory listing. Have you generated one using the `ssh-keygen` command?

Comment: That is the directory listing of `.ssh` on the server, not the client. I feel confident that the contents of `.ssh` on the client are good because my sshkeys work with other machines.

Comment: Hum. Unless the correct key is not in the `authorized_keys` file, I can't see why it's not working. Try to get more information by raising the debugging level: `ssh -vvv`.